# PHP UDP fsockopen fread (RCON)

Tags: php

I want to get a message back after succesfully connected with an UDP address via fsockopen. Connection with a RCON ModManager (game server).

What to expect?
If I use Telnet:
Telnet 31.204.131.9 15502 , I see: 
ModManager Rcon v8.5
Digest seed: iJrrQAkv

Now in PHP:

```
<?php
$_ip        = '31.204.131.9' ; 
$_port      = '15502'; 

if (($socket = fsockopen ('udp://'.$_ip, $_port, $errno, $errstr, 30))) {

    // till here it works, got connected

    // Digest seed? 
    if(fwrite($socket, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n")) { // writing works  } 
    echo fread($socket, 1024); // NOTHING
    fclose($socket);

} 
?>
```

You can try it.. IP and Port valid. Thnx in advance!!

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: Yes, no error in errstr and errno is 0. The fwrite seems to work if i do if(fwrite($socket, "1 2 3\r\n")) {   }.
And fread fails, no error output there either.

Answer (score 0):

When you use telnet you use `tcp` protocol, not `udp`. Try

```
<?php
$_ip        = '31.204.131.9' ; 
$_port      = '15502'; 

if (($socket = fsockopen ($_ip, $_port, $errno, $errstr, 30))) {

    // till here it works, got connected

    // Digest seed? 
    if(fwrite($socket, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n")) { echo "writing works\n";  } 
    echo fread($socket, 1024); // NOTHING
    fclose($socket);

}
```